# How do you safe the state of a running container during reboot of the host?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is there any way to restart the host without loosing all changes that were made to the running container (if the changes were not made on a mounted volume) ?

I have `docker container commit` if I'm running pure docker but I wonder if there is a k8s-way to do it.

Comment: Checkout this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111174/does-kubernetes-have-an-equivalent-to-docker-commit-save

Comment: "save state of running container" - this is anti-pattern, make your images "immutable". From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/): Generally, it is better to use Dockerfiles to manage your images in a documented and maintainable way. Good luck!